# Airflow Jinja template for variable with default value

Tags: jinja2, airflow

According to [the official docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html#default-variables) if you want to use Jinja to fetch a variable and provide a default value, the syntax is:

```
var.value.get('my.var', 'fallback')
```

But in running that on version `1.10.6`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR - 'Variable get does not exist'
```

That is, the parser thinks that I'm looking for a variable named `get` instead of treating `get()` as a function call.

What is the correct syntax for using Jinja to fetch a variable with a default value in case the variable is not set in the server?

Comment: Hey, are you using it this way :{{ var.value.get('my.var', 'fallback') }} ? And where do you have/define this code?

Comment: That's exactly how I'm doing it. It works fine if I just get the variable with `{{ var.value.MY_VAR }}` so I'm sure I got the idea right. I'm sending that as a str as an argument to my custom op.

Comment: This feature seems released in 1.10.7. https://github.com/apache/airflow/releases. [AIRFLOW-1076]. Try upgrading to 1.10.7 or higher and see if that works.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm using Google cloud composer, which is running airflow 1.9.x

Comment: @Emma How do I default using jinja template ? Is it `'{{ var.value.get('my.var', 30) }}'`

Answer (score 1):

The usage of template `{{ var.value.get('my.var', 'fallback') }}` is working for me in Airflow 2.1.